# How to pre warm-up Numba's JIT?

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba, warm-up

I have been struggling with Numba in the sense that whenever I write a function for it, it has a very long warm-up for the first time I use it. I wanted to ask is there a way to prewarm up the JIT function?

For example if I write this function `y=1/(log(x+0.1))^2` as a Numba function:

```
@jit(parallel=True,error_model='numpy')
def f_numba(x_vec): 
    N=len(x_vec)
    res=np.empty(N)
    for i in prange(N):
        x=x_vec[i]
        x=np.log(x+0.1)
        res[i]=1/(x*x)
    return res
```

I used this array to test the speed of the function:

```
N=150000
x_vect=np.random.rand(N)
```

And for measuring the execution time of the function I used this:

```
for i in range(5):
    start=timer()
    f_numba(x_vect)
    print('#',timer()-start)
```

It takes 0.8 seconds for the first run and 0.001 seconds for all subsequent runs. If I could somehow pre-warm-up the JIT function to avoid this latency, it would be great. I tried using the first run with a dummy array with a small size using `x_warm=np.random.rand(10)` and then running `f_numba(x_warm)` but the warm-up time didn't change at all. Any suggestions?

For completionism, here are the libraries called:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import jit, prange
```

I'm using Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.7.

Comment: `jit` stands for "just in time" - it's intended to compile at runtime.  Python is an interpreted language, not (normally) compiled, so pre-compiling isn't really a thing for most cases.  It's possible (that's why `numpy` is so fast, as much of it's pre-compiled c-code in the backend) but it's not generally a simple task.

Comment: You could try `cache=True` to cache the compilation result. Initializing the caching algorithm can also take some time, but it has fur sure a significant effect if you have more than one function.

Comment: @DanielF but why is JIT faster than numpy for large arrays if numpy is precompiled?

Comment: Because `numpy` also has a lot of guard-rails built in to make sure that the package is 'pythonic' and flexible, as well as having some front-end `python` code.  `numba` is super fast, but much less forgiving and dynamic.  And for very large arrays and vectorized `numpy` code (which isn't always possible), `jit` isn't really much faster.

Comment: @max9111 the  cache=True  has no effect until I remove parallel=True, so I can't use multithreading when I create a cache file?

Comment: It was implemented a few releases ago, maybe you are on a very old numba version? Another alternative to numba is numexpr.

Comment: @max9111 my numba is new but my CPU is old (core i7 3rd gen), so maybe that's the reason? My numpy is also 1.16.0 because of tensorflow. I also tried numexpr but it isn't as fast as numba.

Comment: @max9111 I tried it on a newer CPU (AMD 3500u) with Numpy 1.19.3 and Numba  0.51.2. With both parallel=True, cache=True, the result is the same as parallel=True (as if cache=True is ignored). With only cache=True and without parallel=True I get the decreased warm-up (but at the expense of slower next iterations).